# How can I access JavaScript defined in <head> from <body>

Tags: javascript

For example suppose I have

```
function myTest() {
    return "test";
}
```

defined in `<head>`

In body if I try to call myTest() it fails. How can I make functions and variables accessible from body?

Comment: it already is accessible...just call myTest() from inside a <script> tag within your <body>

Comment: This should work just fine. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Do you mean you have it in a `<script>` tag in the head of the document? Is that all you have in the tag?

Answer (score 0):

Script in the `head` tag will get parsed first, so your variables and functions *are* accessible from script in the `body` tag. Your problem must be elsewhere, because the following example works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myTest() {
                return "test";
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert(myTest());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place all JavaScript into `<script>...</script>` tags, OR, place it in event handling attributes (like `onclick`).

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function myTest() { 
         alert("hi");
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="button" onclick="myTest();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Your function in Head..

```
function myFunction(a)
{
  return (a)
}
```

Then call like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   myFunction(12);
</script>
```